# Does SSH protocol version exchange order matter?

Tags: ssh, openssh

I understand that the server will send its SSH version and the client will do the same. What I am wonder is if the order matters.

Additionally, I'm wondering if I could make an SSH server receive an SSH version from a client before sending its own version?

Comment: To whomever voted to close: asking protocol questions seems well within the bounds of SO. But, regardless of suitability, voting to close without an explanation makes it difficult to assess your judgement. And doing so to a new contributor is not very welcoming. Please be more transparent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of the [SSH protocol version exchange](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#section-4.2) is unspecified; it says:

> When the connection has been established, both sides MUST send an
> identification string.  This identification string MUST be
>
> SSH-protoversion-softwareversion SP comments CR LF

The RFC is likely silent on the protocol version exchange order because, practically speaking, it's a race and the order should not matter. When the client's TCP connect is accepted by the server, the client and server send their version information...who gets to the other first is just a matter of speed, traffic, etc.

As a client, you cannot (or should not be able to...) "make" the server wait; it's certainly possible that a particular server implementation waits for client before sending its own information but that's a server implementation detail.

Answer (score 1):

You can Wireshark the SSH connection and see the communication at the TCP level. The SSH client will send its Protocol version first before the server.

I don't think you have the flexibility to change the order of communication. With my SSH client (OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3) I could see that once SYN-ACK is done, the server is waiting for the SSH client to send it's supported protocol version.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the order of the protocol in this case; it's fixed in the RFC, and the order does indeed matter.  The server sends its version as part of the opening request, and then the client sends its version.  Afterward, the two sides exchange a list of algorithms supported by both sides, and the selected algorithm is generally the first one the client supports that's also supported by the server.

While you cannot change the protocol version number announcement, you can, based on the version that the client has sent, choose to offer different algorithms.  For example, some versions of OpenSSH incorrectly implemented `curve25519-sha256@libssh.org`, so a server which knows about this may choose not to offer that algorithm to a broken version of OpenSSH.  Similarly, the client can announce different algorithms to the server based on the server's version announcement.

Comment: [RFC-4353](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4253#section-4.2) says "both sides MUST send an identification string" but it does not specify an order. It seems likely that the client would send its identification string right after the TCP connect is accepted by the server and the server responds its identification string...but that appears to be implementation details not specified in the RFC. Are we looking at the same RFC?

Comment: The protocol matters if either side uses the `SSH-1.99` hack, as specified in §5.1, because the client has to announce the right protocol and/or not send additional data.  I agree that it's not required if you don't use that format and only use SSH 2.0.

Comment: That's a good and important point, @bk2204.